# Is there a way to put 2 variable in one variable? (it is kind of hard to explain)

Tags: c++, variables

For example:

```
int hello1;
int hello2;
int hello3;

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    helloi = 99;
}
```

How can I do something similar like this but with it actually working... also, sorry if I'm being vague here.

Comment: Generalization: When you have sequentially named or numbered variable, odds are very good that your program will be a lot easier to write with an array or [library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: You can put two 16-bit variables inside a 32-bit variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is an array:

```cpp
int hello[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    hello[i] = 99;
}
```

Note that arrays use zero-based indexing, so the indices run from 0 to 2 rather than from 1 to 3.

Comment: Aha, that was what I was looking for. Thanks